# Creating search box using links in html file?

Tags: html, css, web, search-engine

I will preface this question with the fact that I am extremely new to HTML and CSS.

I currently have an engineering page at my company I have inherited that has a ton of links. I have organized into some general categories. However, it has been expressed that they would love a searchbox to search links.

I do not have PHP available to me due to circumstances out of my control. What I do have is all the links in my index.html file with the text they display associated with them.

My thought it that I can create the engine such that it recognizes the  tag, and then searches the "name" associated with the link in the  tag. However, I really have no idea where to start in terms of implementing such a script.

Of course, there may be a much easier way. I am open to any new approaches. I am not biased toward any programming method or language. Thank you so much for the help everyone, and I can provide any other non-NDA information I can.

Comment: could you not just arrange them alphabetically and have an A-Z navigation at the top of each links page?

Comment: That is a possibility. However the way most people seem to use the page was a control-f search. Good suggestion though, I may implement this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at the jQuery UI Automcomplete library http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/, specifically the custom data demo.

I imagine the code something like this (note this is untested and definitely not complete for your purposes):

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var urls = [
   {
      value: "url-text",
      label: "URL Text",
      desc: "URL"
   },
   {
      value: "url2-text",
      label: "URL2 Text",
      desc: "URL2"
   }
];

$('#search').autocomplete({
   minLength: 0,
   source: urls,
   focus: function (event, ui) {
      $('#search').val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
   },
   select: function (event, ui) {
      $('#search').val(ui.item.label);
      $('#url').val(ui.item.desc);
      return false;
   }
})
.data ("autocomplete")._renderItem= function(ul,item) {
   return $('<li></li>")
      .data( 'item.autocomplete', item )
      .append( '<a>' + item.label + '<br />' + item.desc + '</a>' )
      .appendTo( ul );
};


</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="search" />
<p id='url'></p>
</body>
```

Doing it this way does mean you have to keep a separate list of URLs and text in a javascript variable.

Comment: So basically for var urls section, I would need to define each link by its searchable name and url?

Comment: Yes. The search then searches the "label" text, and displays the "desc" text.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in your index.html.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js' />
```

Give each link a common class.  You can then use jQuery to find the link the user is searching for:

```
var search = $("#searchBox").val();
$("a.myLinks[href*="+search+"]"); // uses jQuery to select the link, see jQuery selectors
```

Now you can do things with that link, like show it or navigate to it.